# Running a JQuery animation depending on which option is chosen

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, jquery-animate

I've searched a lot and am sure someone has needed to do this before so sorry if this is a duplicate. I took what I thought was a compilation of the best code I could find online and coudln't get anything to work.

I know the structure is probably way off, but does anyone know why this is wrong.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("select[name='selector']").change(function () {
    $(this).children(':selected').hasClass('three') {
      $("#mover").animate({
        "left": "+=50px"
      });
    };
  });
});
```

[Live example.](http://jsfiddle.net/BHcTj/)

Comment: I actually need a function to say if not the class .three, then do something else as well

Comment: why you applied class to option

Comment: not sure how to check for value of option, more familiar checking classes...but if you can do it with value that would be just as good. But I basically need to check if option three is chosen, animate some other element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things:

1. What you need is  a conditional [`if` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else), that's basic of the language.
2. The [`left` CSS attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/left) is only taken into account when an absolute positioning is being used.

As for the code,

```
#mover {
    position: absolute;
}
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $selector = $("select[name='selector']"), $mover = $("#mover");
    $selector.change(function () {
        if ($selector.children(':selected').hasClass('three')) {
            $mover.animate({
                "left": "+=50px"
            });
        };
    });
});
```

[**You can see it here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/9tQSY/)

Comment: thanks man! That helps and actually makes a lot of sense...how would I duplicate the function for another function that says if not .hasClass of three..?

Comment: @mike, what about negating the condition? `true` --> `!true`

Comment: For the record, you can also use `.not()` jQuery function

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("select[name='selector']").change(function() {
        if($(".three:selected",this).length>0){       
            $("#mover").animate({"left": "+=50px"});
        };
    });
});
```

Here: http://jsfiddle.net/kpT3b/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("select[name='selector']").change(function() {

    if($(this).find('option:selected').text() == "three"){

        $("#mover").animate({"left": "+=50px"});

    }
});
});
```